# What is the difference between "$a" and $a in unix

Tags: shell, unix

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 10 ]
   b="$a"
   while [ "$b" -ge 0 ] do
      echo -n "$b "
     b=`expr $b - 1`
   done
   echo
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done*
```

The above mentioned script gives the answer in triangle while with out the double quotes, it falls one after the other on diff lines.

Comment: Note: "echo -n" doesn't work the same way on all shells, on some systems this will just output "-n" instead of suppressing the newline.

Answer (score 10):

After a variable is expanded to its value, word splitting (i.e. separating the value into tokens at whitespace) and filename wildcard expansion takes place unless the variable is inside double quotes.

Example:

```
var='foo   bar'
echo No quotes: $var
echo With quotes: "$var"
```

will output:

```
No quotes: foo bar
With quotes: foo   bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the difference is how the argument is passed to `echo` function. Effectively `" "` will preserve whitespaces.

This:

```
echo -n "$b "
```

Is translated to:

```
echo -n "<number><space>"
```

While this:

```
echo -n $b<space>
```

Will ignore the trailing space and will just output the number:

```
echo -n <number>
```

Therefore removing all the spaces that are needed for output to look "triangular".

Comment: Not just about preserving whitespace. Consider the case where `b='*'`

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your script:

- no `do` after 1st `while`
- no `;` before `do` after 2nd `while`
- why asterisk on `done*` at the end?

Now to answer your question. 
If used as a paramenter:

- `"$a"` is one argument.
- `$a` (without quotes) is possibly multiple arguments:

Compare:

```
v='a b';  set $v; echo "\$#=$#, \$1=\"$1\",  \$2=\"$2\""  
$#=2, $1="a",  $2="b"

v='a b'; set "$v"; echo "\$#=$#, \$1=\"$1\",  \$2=\"$2\""  
$#=1, $1="a b",  $2=""
```